# Design pattern for switching based on instance of without using instance of keyword

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, instanceof, visitor-pattern

I'm facing a design challenge where I have to switch based on the instance of an object. I have been told that it's a bad idea to use `instanceof` operator in Java. Someone suggested visitor pattern, but in the scenario I'm facing switching has to be done based on one objects instance and not two. So I feel like it might overkill to use visitor pattern which is quite specific and confusing. Please suggest the right approach. Following is a sample

```
VehicleHandler ( Vehicle vehicle){



if( vehicle instanceof Car)


// Do something which cant be tied to Car's impl ( Dont want busiess logic to be in the class itself

else if(vehicle instanceof Bike)
// Do something  
}
```

`Car` and `Bike` implement marker interface `Vehicle`.
There are many classes having functions which takes vehicle as arguments and will need to bifurcate in each of those classes such as `VehicleTransformer`, `VehicleValidator` etc. Those methods are doing completely unrelated actions. Please help me identify the right design pattern for this problem.

Comment: I didn't understand the problem with the visitor pattern.

Comment: Can you edit your question to give us an example of what the handler does for each vehicle type? This might help us decide what's appropriate, eg. could you have `Vehicle::handle()`.

Comment: You don't want to use the visitor pattern and you don't want to use `instanceof`. Anything else you don't want to use? any reason why not use these options?

Comment: To switch on the instance of an object, you create a method in a superclass and implement it differently in the subclass. It's the most basic OO concept. It only works "on one objects instance", not on two, but that's fine according to your requirements.

Comment: What bothers me is that it might a business logic specific to some scenario. Why should that be part of the Vehicle interface? suppose I'm providing vehicle classes and a third part is developing something else on it, why should their specific logic be inside vehicle ?

Comment: In your example use of __instanceoff__ is a clearly **not good**. Method __vehicleHandler(Vehicle v)__ publishes contract saying, __"I will treat all Vehicles equally"__, where as inside its using hidden implementation which treats each vehicles differently. Solution is **"Go Back to your design, its design fault"**, if ignored this part of code will start breaking down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Using `instanceof` is not `bad` per se.
However, it often means that something about the design of classes/interfaces is off.

The visitor pattern is appropriate if you have a limited set of classes that is not open ended.

Instead of having a marker interface, consider adding 
`void accept(VehicleVisitor vv);`

Implement this either into a common abstract base class (if you can) or implement it in Car and Bike like this:

```
void accept(VehicleVisitor vv) {
  vv.visit(this);
}
```

Use a class or interface

```
class VehicleVisitor {
   void visit(Car car) {
      // do car stuff here
   }
   void visit(Bike b) {
      // do bike stuff here
   }
}
```

Then use it in your handling code:

```
Vehicle v = ....;
VehicleVisitor vv = new VehicleVisitor();
v.accept(vv);
```

Also is there a reason you can't add `validate` and `transform` to the Vehicle interface?